# Jmeter : Removing Spaces using RegEx

Tags: jmeter

[image][image]Jmeter :

I am having a JSON from which I have to fetch value of "ci".

I am using the following RegEx : ci:\s*(.*?)\" and getting the following result RegEx tester:
Match count: 1
Match[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efi0z.png)[0]=ci: 434547"
Match[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0fDl.png)=434547

Issue is Match[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efi0z.png)[0] is having spaces because of which while running the load test it says 
: Server Error - Could not convert JSON to Object

Need help is correcting this RegEx.

Comment: IMO the RegEx is fine. `Match[1][0]` obviously gives the text that matched the whole RegEx (property name + value) and `Match[1][1]` contains the first group (the part in brackets), which is the value you were looking for. Could you explain why/where you use `Match[1][0]`? Or maybe some more of the code you are using this in?

Comment: If Match[1][1] is used as value then RegEx is fine. Still getting : HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.xxx.common.xxxException: Server Error - Could not convert JSON to Object</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request processing failed; nested exception is com.xxx.common.xxxException: Server Error - Could not convert JSON to Object</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: Please say what you are doing with the RegEx/Matches/Values! Otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: added 2 png files for reference. Have to fetch the value of CID using Regular Expression extractor and have to pass in JSON. CID changes in every iteration.

Comment: Can't you just set `Match No.: 2`?  Wouldn't that give you just the value? (Besides, what does `Template` mean?)

Comment: Error on Setting Match No.: 2 : description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.34</h3></body></html>

Comment: What is the source value, you apply the RegEx on?

Comment: POST data. {
:   "status":"S",
:   "msg":"Assessment Started - ci: 434613"
} 
ci: space and then number. That's the issue

Comment: What result do you want? Is it `434547` or `ci:434613` or `"ci":"434613"` or ...?

Comment: I am looking only for 434547.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your RegEx is fine. This is the way I would look for it too, the first group *(Match[1])* would give you `434613`, which is the value you are looking for. As I don't know that piece of software you are using, I have no idea why using just that match doesn't work.

Here is an idea to work around that: if the value will always be the only numeric value in the string, you could simplify the RegEx to:

```
\d+
```

This will give you a numeric value that is at least 1 digit long. If there are other numeric values in the string though, but these have different lengths, try this:

```
\d{m,n}   --> between m and n digits long
\d{n,}    --> at least n digits long
\d{0,n}   --> not more than n digits long
```

This is not as secure / reliable as the original RegEx (since it assumes some certain conditions), but it might work in your case, because you don't have to look for groups but just use the whole matched text. Tell me if it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the information Marsze. \d+ or ci:\s*([1-9]+.*?) both are giving me the required value i.e. 434613 but getting some error related Server -- Server Error - Could not convert JSON to Object. Not sure what's wrong. It used to work perfectly fine earlier. Getting it checked internally via Tech team. Will update with the findings.

Comment: Ok, seems like it's not the RegEx after all. Looking forward to your findings!

Comment: Sorry for reverting late. But this got fixed long back. Had some space issue which was creating trouble.